# Xpath: Read a value based on the highest value in a sibling element

Tags: xpath, saxon

I'm trying to read

```
Item/PriceAndTax/PriceComponents[TypeCode = "TAX"]/Rate/DecimalValue
```

from the item where the value of

```
Item/PriceAndTax/PriceComponents[TypeCode = "UPRICE"]/Rate/DecimalValue
```

is the highest. In the sample XML below the correct result would be 10.0. In Item ID 20 the UPRICE is the highest and the TAX value of that item is 10.0.

One idea was to sort the items based on the highest value of /PriceComponents[TypeCode = "UPRICE"]/Rate/DecimalValue and then read from the first (or last) item.

I managed to do the (descending) sorting but I can't figure out how to read the value from the first item:

```
//Item => sort((),function($item){ $item/PriceAndTax/PriceComponents[TypeCode="UPRICE"]/Rate/DecimalValue }) => reverse()
```

Second approach was to try to use max function to compare the values in
Item/PriceAndTax/PriceComponents[TypeCode="UPRICE"]/Rate/DecimalValue
to get the item with highest "UPRICE" value and then read the value of
/PriceComponents[TypeCode="TAX"]/Rate/DecimalValue from that item.

The non-working attempt:

```
//Item/PriceAndTax/PriceComponents[TypeCode="TAX" and Rate/DecimalValue = max(../PriceAndTax/PriceComponents[TypeCode="UPRICE"]/Rate/DecimalValue)]/Rate/DecimalValue/text()
```

The source XML:

```
<Invoice>
    <ID>TEST_INVOICE_123</ID>
    <Buyer>
        <ID>CUSTOMER_01</ID>
    </Buyer>
    <Item>
        <ID>10</ID>
        <Quantity>
            <Quantity>2.0</Quantity>
        </Quantity>
        <Product>
            <InternalID>PROD0100</InternalID>
        </Product>
        <PriceAndTax>
            <NetAmount currencyCode="EUR">50.00</NetAmount>
            <PriceComponents>
                <TypeCode>UPRICE</TypeCode>
                <Rate>
                    <DecimalValue>25.00</DecimalValue>
                </Rate>
            </PriceComponents>
            <PriceComponents>
                <TypeCode>TAX</TypeCode>
                <Rate>
                    <DecimalValue>24.0</DecimalValue>
                </Rate>
            </PriceComponents>
        </PriceAndTax>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <ID>20</ID>
        <Quantity>
            <Quantity>2.0</Quantity>
        </Quantity>
        <Product>
            <InternalID>PROD0200</InternalID>
        </Product>
        <PriceAndTax>
            <NetAmount currencyCode="EUR">105.00</NetAmount>
            <PriceComponents>
                <TypeCode>UPRICE</TypeCode>
                <Rate>
                    <DecimalValue>52.50</DecimalValue>
                </Rate>
            </PriceComponents>
            <PriceComponents>
                <TypeCode>TAX</TypeCode>
                <Rate>
                    <DecimalValue>10.0</DecimalValue>
                </Rate>
            </PriceComponents>
        </PriceAndTax>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <ID>30</ID>
        <Quantity>
            <Quantity>4.0</Quantity>
        </Quantity>
        <Product>
            <InternalID>PROD0300</InternalID>
        </Product>
        <PriceAndTax>
            <NetAmount currencyCode="EUR">120.00</NetAmount>
            <PriceComponents>
                <TypeCode>UPRICE</TypeCode>
                <Rate>
                    <DecimalValue>30.00</DecimalValue>
                </Rate>
            </PriceComponents>
            <PriceComponents>
                <TypeCode>TAX</TypeCode>
                <Rate>
                    <DecimalValue>14.0</DecimalValue>
                </Rate>
            </PriceComponents>
        </PriceAndTax>
    </Item>
</Invoice>
```

The tool I'm using supports Xpath 3.1.

Thanks for help in advance!

BA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saxon has an extension for this, which I've been trying for years to get into the standard:

```
saxon:highest(Item/PriceAndTax, 
    function($pt){
       $pt/PriceComponents[TypeCode = "UPRICE"]/Rate/DecimalValue
    }) 
/PriceComponents[TypeCode = "TAX"]/Rate/DecimalValue
```

If you can't use the extension, then you can write it yourself: see https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#highest-lowest (It's a bit more difficult in pure XPath than in XSLT, but it can be done).

The simplest way might be to define the highest() function in terms of fn:sort:

```
let $highest := function($SEQ, $KEY){fn:sort($SEQ, (), $KEY)[last()]}
return $highest(Item/PriceAndTax, 
    function($pt){
       $pt/PriceComponents[TypeCode = "UPRICE"]/Rate/DecimalValue
    })/PriceComponents[TypeCode = "TAX"]/Rate/DecimalValue
```

Note: if the query isn't schema-aware then you should convert DecimalValue to `xs:decimal` "by hand" to ensure numeric comparison.

Comment: Thank you so much @Michael Kay!    

I was able to make it work using the extension "out of the box". Only a small fix had to be done to add //-prefix the Item.    

So, the working Xpath is:  


````saxon:highest(//Item/PriceAndTax,function($pt){$pt/PriceComponents[TypeCode = "UPRICE"]/Rate/DecimalValue})/PriceComponents[TypeCode = 'TAX']/Rate/DecimalValue````